# How can i get the answer like output? What will be the code

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

How can I get the answer like output? What will be the code.

```
x={1:"datascience", 2:"Machine learning", 3:"Pythone"}
```

Output:

```
{1:{d:1,a:2....}, 2:{M:1,a:2,...},3:{P:1,y:1,..}}
```

Comment: I think you should try it first, Or if you've tried mention the code

Comment: There are lots of examples of Python nested loops on the Internet. Try putting something together and run it. If you still have a problem, post the code you created for us to help diagnose.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = {1: "datascience", 2: "Machine learning", 3: "Pythone"}

output = {}
for key in x.keys():
    output[key] = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(x[key], start=1)}
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'d': 1, 'a': 4, 't': 3, 's': 5, 'c': 10, 'i': 7, 'e': 11, 'n': 9}, 2: {'M' ....
```

However, since dictionary cannot have duplicate keys,

d a t a b .. in database will have the same key for first and second a.. what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: One Interviewer ask this question to solve. In this output is there is any possible that we can count only the letter present in data science. For Example.{1:{''d': 1, 'a': 2, 't': 1, 's': 1, 'c': 2, 'i': 1, 'e': 2, 'n': 1}.

Comment: This answer is wrong; OP needs a dictionary with the amount of times each letter appears in the word, not the index of the last appearance. In case of vague questions like these, instead of answering, you should [leave a comment](//help/privileges/comment) on the question asking for clarification before answering.